# Is there a way to link R to multiple instances of Excel?

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel macro that calls R, which then writes output back to the open excel file. I am using the excel.link package to make the connection from R to Excel.

```
xl.workbook.activate(xl.workbook.name = "Workbook Name.xlsb")
```

This works fine most of the time but occasionally I have multiple instances of Excel open or want to run the macro in multiple instances simultaneously to save on run time. With multiple instances of Excel open it will only find my workbook if it is in the first instance I opened. If it is not in the first instance I get an error like the one below.

```
Error in xl.workbook.activate(xl.workbook.name = "Workbook Name.xlsb") : 
  workbook with name "Workbook Name.xlsb" doesn't exists.
```

Is there a way to link to a workbook regardless of which instance of excel or to identify/specify which instance I want to work with?

R is being called by the excel macro using code similar to the example below, if that is helpful.

```
Sub RunR()
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitUntilComplete As Boolean: waitUntilComplete = True
    Dim errorCode As Long
    
    errorCode = shell.Run("""C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\bin\R.exe""" & " CMD BATCH --vanilla " _
                & """--args Workbook Name.xlsb"" " & """file path for R script""", vbHide, waitUntilComplete)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is this using to "call R" from excel, is it `RExcel`?

Comment: @r2evans, I added an example of what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple instances of Excel files with R. You can select the instance you want with "xlWbk1$Activate()". Afterwards, you can run an Excel macro from R with "xlWbk1$Run("Macro1").

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("D:\\Excel_File_Macro1.xlsm")
xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("D:\\Excel_File_Macro2.xlsm")

xlWbk1$Activate()
xlApp$Run("Macro1")

xlWbk2$Activate()
xlApp$Run("Macro2")
```